# How does C++ code behave under ARC on iOS?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c++

Under ARC, the compiler adds the retain,release calls. What happens to C++ pointers ?
Can Objective C compiler ignore them ?
I dont have much of experience with C++ mixed with Objective C, I was following a box2d tutorial which has the entire engine in c++ but the example is prior to ARC.

Do I have to do something special ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the compiler ignoring C++ pointers"?

Comment: I mean, If a C++ pointer is pointing to a memory location allocated using new in the c++ code, will ARC add a release call for it ?
Or we dont need to do memory management for C++ objects as well ?
Or they are just left as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your comment:

> If a C++ pointer is pointing to a memory location allocated using new in the c++ code, will ARC add a retain call for it ?

You can't retain-release C++ objects - they're not Objective-C objects. Regarding this, the answer to your other questions are as follows:

> What happens to C++ pointers ?

Nothing.

> Do I have to do something special ?

No.

Answer (score 9):

ARC is automatic reference counting and only affects NSObjects et. al (objC objects)
It doesnt affect C or C++ code (those objects you have to manage!)

Comment: Except that it doesn't only affect `NSObject` and its descendants, but all Objective-C objects (including, for example, `NSProxy` who doesn't inherit from `NSObject`).

Comment: @H2CO3 pendantic but correct ;) BUT I had this before that is why I EXPLICTLY wrote `NSObjects et. al (objC objects)` :D